# Running tasks based on conditionals but not registering variable if skipped

Tags: ansible

I want to run some tasks based on a couple of conditionals. Here's the high level process:

1. If var `abc` *has* a value, run task A.
2. If var `abc` is an empty string, run task B.
3. If task A or B return results, run task C.
4. If task A or B don't return results, run task D.

Here's the code (edited to be concise):

```yaml
- name: Task A
  uri:
    url: https://srv.com/path/A
  register: results
  when: abc != ''

- name: Task B
  uri:
    url: https://srv.com/path/B
  register: results
  when: abc == ''

- name: Task C
  uri:
    url: https://srv.com/path/C
  register: results2
  when: results.json.total > 0

- name: Task D
  uri:
    url: https://srv.com/path/D
  register: results2
  when: results.json.total == 0
```

This works fine if var `abc` has a value (ie: task A is skipped). But if task A runs but task B is skipped, the `results` var from task A is overwritten in task B with something like:

```json
"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
```

This being the case I'll never be able to use the results from task A since it's always overwritten by task B even if task B is skipped.

The same applies to C & D--if C runs and D skips, the `results2` variable ends up just saying "skipped... etc".

Is there a way to prevent Ansible from overwriting a variable in the `register` if a task is skipped? Or is there some sort of `switch` functionality in Ansible? Or any other way that would work better to accomplish this?

Edit: Since people are asking for context, this is what I'm doing:

I have a [ConfiForms table](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211860/confiforms-data-forms-workflows-for-confluence?tab=overview&hosting=server) in a Confluence site. ConfiForms has a REST API, so these are all REST calls using the `ansible.builtin.uri` module.

Task A gets a table entry (row) based on one filter if `abc` has a value. Task B gets a table entry based on a different filter if `abc` does not have a value. Task C edits the existing entry if it was found in task A or B. Task D creates a new entry if no existing entry was found in task A or B.

Answer (score 1):

What you've observed is the expected and necessary behavior.

> ***Is there a way to prevent Ansible from overwriting a variable in the register if a task is skipped?***

The short answer is no. At least not in that way, out-of-box and implementing or changing code in Ansible.

This is because, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
    register: result
    when: false

  - debug:
      var: result
```

needs to result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

otherwise it would be impossible to find out what was the result of the former task and if it was skipped or not.

**Documentation**

- [Return Values - `skipped`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#skipped)

---

**Conclusion**

> ***I want to run some tasks based on a couple of conditionals. Here's the high level process:***

You may need to overthink your high level process, use another variable naming, etc. ...

---

> ***Or any other way that would work better to accomplish this?***

I assume yes, maybe a Truth Table, but without any information [what you are really try to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576) this might be unanswerable, at least for me.

Comment: I updated my question with what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: If I used a different variable for each task/condition, I'd need maybe 8-12 tasks to accomplish this, which seems inefficient and I'm trying to avoid. It seems like it should be doable in fewer tasks but I haven't figured out how.